# verifying dates in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My Enddate is 2009-05-31    (using sql server)

```
@EndDate  datetime
select startdate = dateadd(mm,-12,@EndDate)
```

If my EndDate = 2009-05-31
with code above will my
StartDate = 31-05-2008    is my code correct?

I want my senddate to be in the month of April so

```
month(senddate) = month(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate))
```

is my code above correct?

Comment: If your code returns result that you expect, than it's correct, otherwise it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below

```
declare @EndDate  datetime
set @EndDate = '20090531'
select dateadd(mm,0,@EndDate) -- dummy
,dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate) -- april returns 30/4
,dateadd(mm,-2,@EndDate) -- march returns 31/3
,dateadd(mm,-3,@EndDate) -- february returns 28/2
```

More simple

```
month(senddate) = month(dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate))
```

example

```
declare @EndDate  datetime
set @EndDate = '20090531'
select month(dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate)) -- returns 4 (april)
,month(dateadd(mm,-2,@EndDate)) -- returns 3 (march)
,month(dateadd(mm,-3,@EndDate)) -- returns 2 (february)
```

Start of month

```
declare @EndDate  datetime
set @EndDate = '20090531'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate)),112)+'01'
```

Comment: If I want to start from 1st of April, what will be the code?

Comment: dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate)   returns 30/4  if I want 2008-04-01, what will be the code?

Comment: ok so it covers all days in the month then...........no need to worry about specific day  so no need of

Comment: so no need of dateadd(day,-29,dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate) to make it 2008-04-01?

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate)),112)+'01' convert will return '200904' and by concatenating with '01' you get first day of the month '20090401'

Comment: returns date as varchar with (ansi)format yyyymmdd

Comment: I have voted for your answer.....Thanks again :)

Comment: Voting or not, thanks is always welcome :)